# Programmatically logging into Yammer

Tags: yammer, scribe

Editing my previous question - I have a scenario where, from with in a JAVA application, I have to login to Yammer, and create a topic, get back the topic id into my application. My enterprise has SSO enabled. But I guess SSO may not be of much significance since I am doing a programmatic log in. What are the APIs that would allow me to open a session with Yammer? I am looking at ways in which I can get a auth key back, and a session handle.

Thanks,

Comment: What does PLM stand for? What is the purpose of your application? i.e. the business outcome you want to achieve.

Comment: PLM stands for Product Lifecycle Management. However, please disregard the PLM part. Please read the question like this. A JAVA based application, needs to integrate with Yammer. Programatically, on click of a button in that JAVA application, a session needs to be opened up in Yammer, get a auth key, call the topic generation api, get the topic id.

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the [Yammer API Documentation](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/). Yammer API supports the rest protocol so it shouldn't be any issue integrating it with JAVA application. Login to [Yammer developer center](https://developer.yammer.com) with your enterprise credentials. you need to [create an app](https://www.yammer.com/client_applications) and get the AppId/ClientId. The operation that requires Authentication would be acheived by passing the a client token and authentication token. Everything is very well documented on the developer center.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already gone through the documentation. However, I have a question that remained un answered even after going through it. To log in to Yammer, when I use Rest APIs,I use the HTTP connection, which needs me to launch a browser, authenticate the connection. This is precisely what I want to avoid. I don't want the user to see any browser launch, he clicks a button from the java application, and he should get the topic id, no manual authentication, no manual intervention. I am not able to get into Yammer without launching a browser. Appreciate your advice.

Comment: You can't avoid logging in because it's a feature of how the OAuth flow works so you just have to accept it and move on.